# how to load the data from the auth module of nuxtjs in a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am trying to access the data that is in @nuxt/auth in a component, however when I log in and the component loads it does not show the requested data but when refreshing the page if it shows the data.

what would be the ideal way to load this data, for now I am doing so:

```
computed: {
  user() {
   return this.$auth.user;
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`$auth` doesn't change reactively without new requests to the backend, so `computed` is not the best place. Using asyncData or fetch to set this object to a simple data or state seems better, or even use directly `$auth.user`.